# Outlook add-in commands and macOS version

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

We are developing an Outlook add-in (using Javascript API version 1.3 and add-in commands) that supports Outlook 2016 for Mac. Our test systems have macOS Siera (10.12.6) but one tester is getting blank task panes and the only thing that is different is her system has macOS El Capitan (10.11.6).

Is there an minimum macOS required for Outlook add-in commands? The only reference to a requirement I could find was an old MS article that pre-dates add-in commands that mentions macOS 10.10.

Or has anyone seen the blank task pane issue? The task panes have a title, but blank content. No add-in error is shown. On the same test system our add-in is working on OWA for Safari.

Thanks

Comment: Follow-up: That test system was updated to Siera and the add-in now works on that system.

Answer (score 0):

Mac outlook is providing active support only to OS version 10.11 and above. Kindly update the OS and verify if its working.